# ValueError: Series can only be used with a 2-level MultiIndexを解決したいです

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook

先週末よりPythonを始めたばかりの初心者です。ネットデータベースを取り込み、定点的に分析するツールを作りたく、調べながら、その雛形を作成中です。
詳しい人でしたら、すぐに原因がわかる内容かもしれませんが、お助けくださると感謝します。

### これまでに試したこと

コードを実行しますと、以下のエラーメッセージが出ます。

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-179-6e43b379bc6b> in <module>
      6 exog_vars = ['expersq', 'union', 'married', 'year']
      7 #被説明変数には data.lwage を指定する
----> 8 mod = PooledOLS(data.lwage, sm.add_constant(data[exog_vars]))
      9 pooled_res = mod.fit()
     10 print(pooled_res)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/linearmodels/panel/model.py in __init__(self, dependent, exog, weights)
    776         weights: Optional[PanelDataLike] = None,
    777     ) -> None:
--> 778         super().__init__(dependent, exog, weights=weights)
    779 
    780     @classmethod

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/linearmodels/panel/model.py in __init__(self, dependent, exog, weights)
    228         weights: Optional[PanelDataLike] = None,
    229     ) -> None:
--> 230         self.dependent = PanelData(dependent, "Dep")
    231         self.exog = PanelData(exog, "Exog")
    232         self._original_shape = self.dependent.shape

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/linearmodels/panel/data.py in __init__(self, x, var_name, convert_dummies, drop_first, copy)
    200             x = DataFrame(x)
    201         elif isinstance(x, Series):
--> 202             raise ValueError("Series can only be used with a 2-level MultiIndex")
    203 
    204         if isinstance(x, DataFrame):

ValueError: Series can only be used with a 2-level MultiIndex
```

### 現状のコード

次の通りです。

```
from linearmodels import PooledOLS
import statsmodels.api as sm
exog_vars = ['expersq', 'union', 'married', 'year']
mod = PooledOLS(data.lwage, sm.add_constant(data[exog_vars]))
pooled_res = mod.fit()
print(pooled_res)
```

Comment: この記事 [Examples - linearmodels 4.19 (+12)](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/devel/panel/examples/examples.html) が関連していると思われますが、それで記事上の版数やソースコードと何か違い(タイプミスとか)があるか確認してありますか？ 何か変更しているなら、その部分が影響している可能性が考えられます。

Answer (score 0):

何か環境・版数・作業手順に関する問題と思われます。
あるいは質問時の以前に何か別の作業を行っていて、そのままjupyterを再起動せず使い続け、その影響で状態が変わってエラーになったとかが考えられます。

以下の環境で：
Windows10 20H2
Anaconda3 Individual 2020.11
Anaconda環境はconda update condaで最新化
Python 3.8.6
Pandas 1.2.2

lineamodels 4.18 conda install

以下の記事より：
[Examples - linearmodels 4.19 (+12)](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/devel/panel/examples/examples.html)

[1]のソースをコピー・実行後：

> ```
> from linearmodels.datasets import wage_panel
> import pandas as pd
>
> data = wage_panel.load()
> year = pd.Categorical(data.year)
> data = data.set_index(["nr", "year"])
> data["year"] = year
> print(wage_panel.DESCR)
> print(data.head())
> ```

質問のソースをコピー・実行して：

```
from linearmodels import PooledOLS
import statsmodels.api as sm
exog_vars = ['expersq', 'union', 'married', 'year']
mod = PooledOLS(data.lwage, sm.add_constant(data[exog_vars]))
pooled_res = mod.fit()
print(pooled_res)
```

正常に処理が行われた結果が表示されます。

```
                          PooledOLS Estimation Summary                          
================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                  lwage   R-squared:                        0.1246
Estimator:                  PooledOLS   R-squared (Between):              0.0902
No. Observations:                4360   R-squared (Within):               0.1646
Date:                Wed, Feb 17 2021   R-squared (Overall):              0.1246
Time:                        14:46:24   Log-likelihood                   -3149.2
Cov. Estimator:            Unadjusted                                           
                                        F-statistic:                      61.920
Entities:                         545   P-value                           0.0000
Avg Obs:                       8.0000   Distribution:                 F(10,4349)
Min Obs:                       8.0000                                           
Max Obs:                       8.0000   F-statistic (robust):             61.920
                                        P-value                           0.0000
Time periods:                       8   Distribution:                 F(10,4349)
Avg Obs:                       545.00                                           
Min Obs:                       545.00                                           
Max Obs:                       545.00                                           
                                                                                
                             Parameter Estimates                              
==============================================================================
            Parameter  Std. Err.     T-stat    P-value    Lower CI    Upper CI
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          1.3454     0.0222     60.606     0.0000      1.3019      1.3889
expersq       -0.0021     0.0003    -7.5081     0.0000     -0.0026     -0.0015
union          0.1768     0.0176     10.032     0.0000      0.1423      0.2114
married        0.1521     0.0159     9.5417     0.0000      0.1209      0.1834
year.1981      0.1187     0.0303     3.9144     0.0001      0.0592      0.1781
year.1982      0.1843     0.0306     6.0168     0.0000      0.1243      0.2444
year.1983      0.2431     0.0313     7.7581     0.0000      0.1817      0.3046
year.1984      0.3322     0.0324     10.236     0.0000      0.2685      0.3958
year.1985      0.4112     0.0341     12.048     0.0000      0.3443      0.4781
year.1986      0.5039     0.0365     13.806     0.0000      0.4323      0.5754
year.1987      0.5952     0.0396     15.026     0.0000      0.5176      0.6729
==============================================================================
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
回答頂きましたコードで実行出来ました。
もう一度一から見直してみます。感謝しております。